# Error in Jenkins connection to stash

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, bitbucket-server

I'm trying to configure my Jenkins job to connect to Altassian Stash. I'm using the [git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) for Jenkins.

Here the job configuration details- under source code management, choose git:

Repository Url: https://lab.xyz.com/stash/scm/projects/sandbox.git

Credentials: jenkinuser/password (defined in the global credentials of Jenkins configuration)

I get the following error:

```
Failed to connect to repository:  
Could not init C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson1141847846411984817tmp
```

(The tmp name keeps changing).

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: It might be a permissions issue on your local machine writing to the TEMP directory.

Comment: We had to downgrade to git plugin version 1.5.0 and git client plugin version 1.0.7 and it worked.

Comment: Was getting similar error on Red Hat. Fixed it by installing `git` on Jenkins Server:
`yum install -y git`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had to downgrade to git plugin version 1.5.0 and git client plugin version 1.0.7 and it worked. We are running Jenkins version 1.577.

That git plugin takes the url as: https://jenkinuser:password@lab.xyz.com/stash/scm/projects/sandbox.git

Comment: It's much easier (and secure) to authenticate using SSH :)

Answer (score 12):

I know its a little late but this worked for me:

> Check if you have install git on the Jenkins server, and check if you
>   have set the git executable path in the Jenkins configuration
>
> More specifically go to 'Manage Jenkins' -> 'Global Tool Configuration' and
>   check the 'Path to Git executable' field.

Source: https://serverfault.com/a/669487/212634

Answer (score 2):

In Global Tool Configuration, where you "set" GIT location:
C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe. Do not forget to include ‘.exe’ extension.
It is for Windows.