# Jenkins HTTPS Git

Tags: git, jenkins

currently working on a proof of concept with automation, so i am trying to get Jenkins working with our GIT repo, but after filling in the credentials i am getting a weird error.

```
Failed to connect to repository : Could not init C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\temp\hudson426153378954858779tmp
```

this happens at the config screen of the  project in jenkins at the git selection

ignoring this error gives me this log from trying to get the repo:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Users\<name>\.jenkins\workspace\test-build
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://gitlab.<project name>.git
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core\git.exe init C:\Users\<name>\.jenkins\workspace\test-build # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

- the git repo is private
- Running on Apache tomcat 8.0.20
- Jenkins Version 1.602.war
- Windows 7 pro x64

Comment: Seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933107/error-in-jenkins-connection-to-stash) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/i2MzOZmSjxM)? Basically, try a) fixing path to git executable b) removing the temp folder c) updating/downgrading git plugin d) using egit integration. You should fix the config screen problem first, git integration won't work before.

Comment: Are you using ssh? if you do try first to clone it with ssh to see if this its a permission issue

Comment: Downgrading the git plugin seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

the best thing is to use JGIT rather using git and downgrading git plugin, It worked for me.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the current git plugin may have issues. As a more general comment, I have found that running something like

```
git ls-remote -h https://gitlab.<project name>.git HEAD
```

by hand (on the command line on the Jenkins server) is a useful step in debugging the connection (and getting the two sides past any manual prompts that are needed).